# Retrieve return type from function

Tags: kotlin

I was investigating how the compiler infers the return type of functions depending on the return statements. Then I came across something that perplexed me.

I have this Kotlin function:

```
fun ambigousTypeEval(sport: String) = when (sport) {
  "cricket" -> -1
  else -> "I like $sport"
}
```

It can return an `Int` OR a `String`, so it's compile time type is `Any` (i.e. if you call this function and assign it's return value to a variable, that variable will be of type `Any`).

However, when I load that code in the kotlinc REPL, and check it's type, I am getting a different type for different inputs...

```
>>> examples.ambigousTypeEval("cricket")::class
examples.ambigousTypeEval("cricket")class kotlin.Int

>>> examples.ambigousTypeEval("football")::class
examples.ambigousTypeEval("football")class kotlin.String
```

What's going on here?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I want to know how to find out the compile time type of the function. I.e. I was expecting to see something like: `(String) -> Any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the edit:

You must get a reference to the function first:

```
val func = examples::ambiguousTypeEval
```

This is a [`KFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/index.html) instance.

Now simply retrieve its [`returnType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/return-type.html):

```
val returnType: KType = examples::ambiguousTypeEval.returnType
```

In this case, the return type will be a `KType` corresponding to `Any`.

You can retrieve the parameter types via [`parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/parameters.html).

Comment: See my question edit, hopefully clarifies what I was expecting to happen.

Comment: @ThomasCook I've added more at the top of my answer

Comment: Yup that's what I was after. sorry for the confusing question,